# NPM package for NPM scripts

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to write an npm package that will add a specific npm script to whatever package.json on which it is depended. Nothing in the npm package.json / script docs is bringing me remotely close.

I'm basically trying to do this:

1. I install an npm package (call it 'cool-thing')
2. `cool-thing`, by installing, adds an npm script to my existent package.json
3. I can call cool-thing on the command line and it will perform whatever action is specified in the package.json

Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: are you trying to implement dynamic modules? When you say "adds an npm script" do you mean something like `start: <script>`? One way to keep it clean could be to prepare a generic script in the package.json before anything gets added to it from `cool-thing`. This generic script would receive a parameter that you'd use internally to run a specific script.

Comment: @Sebas Yep, exactly like `start-thing: <script>`. I wrote a cli node package that I want to run with a simple command - I thought I'd use the `package.json` to hold the command key.

Comment: so, what's not working exactly? It should work.

Comment: if `cool-thing` is a CLI command, you can run `npx cool-thing`, which is kind of like running `cool-thing` if it were installed globally (with `npm install -g`). NPX can run binary files inside your `node_modules` folder. (NPX is automatically installed with NPM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are working on a package `cool-parent` which depends on package `cool-thing` because you want to run the executable that `cool-thing` provides.

Normally, you would manually modify the `cool-parent` `package.json` to add a script:

```
"scripts": {
   "cool-thing": "cool-thing"
}
```

Now for user convenience, you would like 1) to automate this modification. Not only that, you want to 2) make the modification automatically after the package is installed as a dependency.

There are some drawbacks to part 2, the developer of `cool-parent`

1. might not want to add a script,
2. might already have a script called `cool-thing`,
3. might not have a `package.json`,
4. ...

I consider making modification outside of the package itself during install time to be an undesirable side effect.

If you still want to do it, you can using a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script in `cool-thing`. You would need to figure out the location of the `package.json` of the parent if there is one through working directories and perhaps environment variables that npm provides.